# Changing character in a string of characters

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

I was wondering regarding how to edit the following column that exists in oracle DB

```
PPPPFPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPFPPPPPPPP
```

I want to only set the 5th `F` with `P` without affecting other structure. 
I've around 700 records and I want to change that position (5th) on all users to `P`

I was thinking of PLSQL instead of a query, so could you please advice.

Thanks

Comment: PPPPFPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPFPPPPPPPP
FFFPFPPFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
PPFPFFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPPFPFP
PFPPFPPPFPPFPPFPFPPFPFPPFPPFPFPFPPPPPP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Klashxx answer is a good one - REGEXP_REPLACE is the way to go.  Old fashioned way built up bit by bit so you can see what's going on :

```
WITH 
 test_data (text)
 AS  (SELECT '1234F1234F1234F1234F1234F1234F1234' FROM DUAL
 )
SELECT 
 text
,INSTR(text,'F',1,5)    --fifth occurence
,SUBSTR(text,1,INSTR(text,'F',1,5)-1) --substr up to that point
,SUBSTR(text,1,INSTR(text,'F',1,5)-1)||'P'    --add P
,SUBSTR(text,1,INSTR(text,'F',1,5)-1)||'P'||SUBSTR(text,INSTR(text,'F',1,5)+1)    --add remainder of string
FROM
 test_data
;
```

So what you're trying to do would be  something like

```
UPDATE <your table>
SET <your column> = SUBSTR(<your column>,1,INSTR(<your column>,'F',1,5)-1)||'P'||SUBSTR(<your column>,INSTR(<your column>,'F',1,5)+1)
```

..assuming you want to update all rows

Comment: Thank you so much 
So this will add new character to the sequence and shift all other characters to the right... Ending up with sth like 
PPPPPFPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPFPPPPPPPP 
instead of 
PPPPFPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPFPPPPPPPP

I want to replace one character at the 5th position or 6th position with new one let's assume from N(no) to Y(yes)

Comment: Logically it will replace the 5th occurrence of 'F' with a 'P'.  It does this by taking all the chars before the 5th F, append a P and then add back all the characters that originally followed.  The length of the string is unchanged.  I used an example with numbers and Fs to make that easier to see

Comment: but if you want to replace the 5th character in the string (rather than the 5th occurrence of a character) - this would be a different thing altogether (much simpler).  If you want to replace char 5 then reference this questions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2916488/remove-a-character-from-a-given-position-on-oracle

Comment: Yes sir I want to replace as if change that bit

Comment: I don't have occurrence i only know the exact position of that character

Comment: Sample rows:
---------------------------------------
PPPPFPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPFPPPPPPPP
FFFPFPPFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF
PPFPFFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPFPPFPFP
PFPPFPPPFPPFPPFPFPPFPFPPFPPFPFPFPPPPPP

Comment: OK, then follow the link in my earlier comment - that answers your question very well

Comment: Thank you so much it the substr is the option ... thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [`REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm):

```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE('PPPPFPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPFPPPPPPPP', '^(\w{4}).(.*)', '\1P\2') AS COL_REGX FROM dual

COL_REGX
--------------------------------------
PPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPPFPPPPPPPP
```

Comment: doing it in regular expression is as if we're assumeing there will always be P before and P after, but in my case, I only have the position of that char that I want to change it's the 5th position (6th bit) in varchar column.

Answer (score 0):

The solution below looks for the first five characters at the beginning of the input string. If found, it keeps the first four unchanged and it replaces the fifth with the letter P. Note that if the input string is four characters or less, it is left unchanged. (This includes `NULL` as the input string, shown in the WITH clause which creates sample strings and also in the output - note that the output has FIVE rows, even though there is nothing visible in the last one.)

```
with
     test_data ( str ) as (
       select 'ABCDEFGH' from dual union all
       select 'PPPPF'    from dual union all
       select 'PPPPP'    from dual union all
       select '1234'     from dual union all
       select null       from dual
     )
select str, regexp_replace(str, '^(.{4}).', '\1P') as replaced
from   test_data
;

STR       REPLACED
--------  --------
ABCDEFGH  ABCDPFGH
PPPPF     PPPPP
PPPPP     PPPPP
1234      1234


5 rows selected.
```

Answer (score 0):

Flip the 5th 'bit' to a 'P' where it's currently an 'F'.

```
update table
set column = regexp_replace(column , '^(.{4}).', '\1P')
where regexp_like(column , '^.{4}F');
```